# Type member layout customization

Tags: c#, resharper, regions, resharper-7.1

I'm trying to put all what belongs to my WPF Commands into one region with ReSharpers `Code Cleanup`. I've tried following XML inside my working pattern. But this isn't working. I guess the match isn't working.
Also I would like to move methods with specific parameters. Is this anyway possible?
I'm using ReSharper 7.1.1.

```
<Entry>
  <Match>
   <Or>
      <ImplementsInterface CLRName="ICommand">
      <ImplementsInterface CLRName="ISimpleCommand">
   </Or>
  </Match>
  <Sort>
    <Access Order="public internal protected-internal protected private" />
  </Sort>
  <Group Region="Commands"/>
</Entry>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few emails with Jetbrains came out that it is not possible.

A way could be using regular expressions. See [here](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/01/in-depth-look-at-customizing-type-layout-with-resharper/)

```
<Name Is="$val” [IgnoreCase=”true/false”]>
```

Regular expression. IgnoreCase indicates whether to ignore case

```
<HasAttribute CLRName=”$val” [Inherit=”true/false”]>
```

Regular expression. Inherit indicates if it applies to inherited classes.